# Mac Pro (2013) crashes a lot since upgrade from Mavericks (now on High Sierra)

Tags: crash, mac-pro

I have a Mac Pro. Since upgrading from the original Mavericks it crashes - a lot.  The way the Mac freezes varies with each new OS X upgrade and I'm currently on High Sierra but I suspect it's fallen foul of the dreaded graphics card recall issue but can't prove it and the recall only applied to the larger two variants of the graphics.

If anyone can glean any info from the log below I'd be really grateful or if others have had experience that'd be good to know too.

Here's the log generated from my last forced restart.

```
   Anonymous UUID:       3E7A5470-A7B1-91D8-D0AA-4F17EEA2DB92

Tue Apr 24 00:11:46 2018

    *** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff7f9ad7fd7a): "bool IO Ac cel DisplayMachine2::display_mode_did_change(uint32_t): vendor driver returns false"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com .apple. x b s/Sources/IOAcceleratorFamily_kexts/IOAcceleratorFamily-378.18.1/Kext2/I O Ac celDisplayMachine.cpp:490

>>> Spaces only added in previous lines as ASK thought it was spam <<<

Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address 0xffffff8da6a53580 : 0xffffff801806e166 0xffffff8da6a535d0 : 0xffffff8018196714 0xffffff8da6a53610 : 0xffffff8018188a00 0xffffff8da6a53690 : 0xffffff8018020180 0xffffff8da6a536b0 : 0xffffff801806dbdc 0xffffff8da6a537e0 : 0xffffff801806d99c 0xffffff8da6a53840 : 0xffffff7f9ad7fd7a 0xffffff8da6a53870 : 0xffffff7f9adac7d5 0xffffff8da6a538b0 : 0xffffff7f9922ca46 0xffffff8da6a53960 : 0xffffff7f99219a10 0xffffff8da6a539a0 : 0xffffff7f99223f15 0xffffff8da6a539c0 : 0xffffff7f9921ead0 0xffffff8da6a53a30 : 0xffffff7f9922a5e3 0xffffff8da6a53a50 : 0xffffff7f9922aede 0xffffff8da6a53a90 : 0xffffff7f9922acd0 0xffffff8da6a53ad0 : 0xffffff80186c2218 0xffffff8da6a53b20 : 0xffffff7f99230f2b 0xffffff8da6a53b70 : 0xffffff80186cae07 0xffffff8da6a53cb0 : 0xffffff8018144a84 0xffffff8da6a53dc0 : 0xffffff8018073680 0xffffff8da6a53e10 : 0xffffff80180509dd 0xffffff8da6a53e60 : 0xffffff80180634eb 0xffffff8da6a53ef0 : 0xffffff80181735ad 0xffffff8da6a53fa0 : 0xffffff8018020986 Kernel Extensions in backtrace: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(519.15)[D5F2A20D-CAB0-33B2-91B9-E8755DFC34CB]@0xffffff7f99210000->0xffffff7f99258fff dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[1850E7DA-E707-3027-A3AA-637C80B57219]@0xffffff7f98894000 com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(378.18.1)[BAA0383C-9650-3934-B04A-69008F757A2C]@0xffffff7f9ad75000->0xffffff7f9ae0bfff dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[54CD88E5-9FD7-30FC-89A0-E4B2D0CE6F85]@0xffffff7f991d5000 dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(211.12)[E998B85B-3174-3C25-B82B-C0D8BD9720E5]@0xffffff7f9ad59000 dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[1850E7DA-E707-3027-A3AA-637C80B57219]@0xffffff7f98894000 dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(519.15)[D5F2A20D-CAB0-33B2-91B9-E8755DFC34CB]@0xffffff7f99210000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version: 17E199

Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 17.5.0: Mon Mar 5 22:24:32 PST 2018; root:xnu-4570.51.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64 Kernel UUID: 1B55340B-0B14-3026-8A47-1E139DB63DA3 Kernel slide: 0x0000000017e00000 Kernel text base: 0xffffff8018000000 __HIB text base: 0xffffff8017f00000 System model name: MacPro6,1 (Mac-F60DEB81FF30ACF6)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 13779686744597 last loaded kext at 8311432868782: com.apple.driver.MaxTranserSizeOverrideDriver 439.50.6 (addr 0xffffff7f9ba94000, size 16384) loaded kexts: com.bitdefender.TMProtection 5.0.0 com.bitdefender.FileProtect 1 com.paragon-software.filesystems.ntfs 318.3.14 com.uaudio.driver.UAD2System 9.2.0 jp.co.yamaha.driver.YamahaFWAudioDriver 1.4.3 jp.co.yamaha.driver.YamahaFWAsync 1.2.4 com.sony.driver.dsccamDeviceInfo00 1 com.bitdefender.SelfProtect 1.1 com.apple.driver.MaxTranserSizeOverrideDriver 439.50.6 com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs 1.10 com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 133 com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch 92 com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC 1.70 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager 6.0.5f3 com.apple.driver.AGPM 110.23.33 com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler 2.7.0d0 com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim 1.0.0 com.apple.filesystems.autofs 3.0 com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient 3.6.5 com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl 1.5.4 com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer 1.6.6 com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4000 1.6.6 com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy 3.18.48 com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver 281.51 com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics 3.18.48 com.apple.driver.AppleHDA 281.51 com.apple.driver.AppleHV 1 com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet 1.0.1 com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry 1 com.apple.driver.eficheck 1 com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X 7.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleLPC 3.1 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.1 com.apple.driver.AppleMGPUPowerControl 3.18.48 com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin 1.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog 1 com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver 4.1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelMCEReporter 107 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0 com.apple.kext.AMD7000Controller 1.6.6 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU 6.0.5f3 com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient 404.30.2 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBStorageCoexistentDriver 439.50.6 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBODD 439.50.6 com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver 3.0.1 com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext 407.50.6 com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1 com.apple.BootCache 40 com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0 com.apple.filesystems.apfs 748.51.0 com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI 5.5.9 com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC 1240.29.1a7 com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet 10.3.1 com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort 329.50.2 com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC 6.1 com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons 6.1 com.apple.driver.AppleRTC 2.0 com.apple.driver.AppleHPET 1.8 com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS 2.1 com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC 1.7 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 220.50.1 com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall 183 com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet 8 com.apple.security.quarantine 3 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement 220.50.1 com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard 205 com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 133 com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver 6.0.5f3 com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver 1404.4 com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport 1404.3 com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily 11 com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController 1.0.18d1 com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4030HWLibs 1.0 com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2 378.18.1 com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices 1.6.6 com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 281.51 com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib 526 com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 675.6 com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin 675.12 com.apple.driver.AppleSSE 1.0 com.apple.iokit.IOSurface 211.12 com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP 2.2.9 com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler 3.18.48 com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 281.51 com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 281.51 com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI 1.0.14d1 com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl 3.18.48 com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert 1.1.0 com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport 519.15 com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0 com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin 1.0.0 com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8 com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily 1.0.0 com.apple.kext.AMDSupport 1.6.6 com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl 3.18.48 com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily 519.15 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink 4.1.4 com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.5f3 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 6.0.5f3 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport 6.0.5f3 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily 6.0.5f3 com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass 4.0.4 com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice 404.30.2 com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily 1.8 com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily 1.8 com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily 1.8 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio 312.6 com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily 206.5 com.apple.vecLib.kext 1.2.0 com.apple.driver.usb.cdc 5.0.0 com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice 1.2 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub 1.2 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter 5.5.3 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIUpAdapter 2.1.3 com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter 5.5.3 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily 5.5.3 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.3 com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme 3 com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily 4.7.0 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI 4.7.2 com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.7.8 com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage 301.40.2 com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family 1200.12.2 com.apple.driver.corecapture 1.0.4 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI 1.2 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI 1.2 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub 900.4.1 com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0 com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient 1.0.1b8 com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily 288 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI 1.2 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI 1.2 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter 1.0 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties 1.2 com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM 2.1 com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily 1.1 com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0 com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime 2.1 com.apple.security.sandbox 300.0 com.apple.kext.AppleMatch 1.0.0d1 com.apple.driver.DiskImages 480.50.10 com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore 28.30 com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore 2 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM 439.50.6 com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity 1.0.5 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver 140.50.3 com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice 404.30.2 com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily 404.30.2 com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1 com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0 com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost 1 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController 1.0 com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager 1.0.1 com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor 1 com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily 31 com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily 675.12 com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily 3.4 com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform 6.1 com.apple.driver.AppleSMC 3.1.9 com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9 com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily 1.4 com.apple.kec.pthread 1 com.apple.kec.corecrypto 1.0 com.apple.kec.Libm 1

EOF Model: MacPro6,1, BootROM MP61.0123.B00, 4 processors, Quad-Core Intel Xeon E5, 3.7 GHz, 12 GB, SMC 2.20f18 Graphics: AMD FirePro D300, AMD FirePro D300, PCIe Graphics: AMD FirePro D300, AMD FirePro D300, PCIe Memory Module: DIMM1, 4 GB, DDR3 ECC, 1866 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3430454738424657422D4A532D4620 Memory Module: DIMM2, 4 GB, DDR3 ECC, 1866 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3430454738424657422D4A532D4620 Memory Module: DIMM3, 4 GB, DDR3 ECC, 1866 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3430454738424657422D4A532D4620 AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x135), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.37.29.1a7) Bluetooth: Version 6.0.5f3, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports Network Service: Ethernet 1, Ethernet, en0 Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en2 PCI Card: AMD FirePro D300, Display Controller, Slot-1 PCI Card: AMD FirePro D300, Display Controller, Slot-2 PCI Card: pci11c1,5901, IEEE 1394 Open HCI, Thunderbolt@81,0,0 PCI Card: pci1b21,612, AHCI Controller, Thunderbolt@155,0,0 PCI Card: pci1b21,612, AHCI Controller, Thunderbolt@156,0,0 PCI Card: pci1b21,612, AHCI Controller, Thunderbolt@157,0,0 PCI Card: pci1b21,612, AHCI Controller, Thunderbolt@158,0,0 Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0512F, 500.28 GB Serial ATA Device: ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB, 1 TB Serial ATA Device: ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB, 1 TB Serial ATA Device: ST1000LM024 HN-M101MBB, 1 TB Serial ATA Device: ST2000LM015-2E8174, 2 TB USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus USB Device: Hub USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus USB Device: USB3.0 Hub USB Device: USB3.0 Hub USB Device: USB2.0 Hub USB Device: XP-960 Series USB Device: USB2.0 Card Reader USB Device: USB2.0 Hub USB Device: CodeMeter-Stick USB Device: eLicenser USB Device: Apple USB SuperDrive USB Device: ESI M8U XL FireWire Device: MR816 series, Yamaha, Up to 400 Mb/sec Thunderbolt Bus: Mac Pro, Apple Inc., 19.2 Thunderbolt Device: Thunderbolt to FireWire Adapter, Apple Inc., 3, 5.6 Thunderbolt Bus: Mac Pro, Apple Inc., 19.2 Thunderbolt Device: MultiDock, Blackmagic Design, 1, 22.1 Thunderbolt Bus: Mac Pro, Apple Inc., 19.2 strong text
```

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you have the D300 GPU. The GUI freeze is a known problem for the Mac Pro (2013) with this GPU – at least in the community (see this [MacRumors forum thread](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/mac-pro-late-2013-gpu-driver-issues.1860297/)). Apple never acknowledged it and it's very hard to reproduce.

It's basically a hardware problem that occurs mostly when doing hardware video decoding or 3D graphics.

When running windows, there's a short blackout but the system doesn't lock up. Under more recent macOS versions, the GUI freezes.

Since macOS 10.13.4, sometimes there are at least panic logs and Crash Reporter allows sending them to Apple. Let's hope they'll take a look and fix their driver.

What you can do once your GUI is frozen:

- Connect to your Mac using SSH (needs to be set up beforehand) and reboot it that way
- Using the key combination `Control–Command–Media Eject` to reboot your Mac more or less gracefully (as documented [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236))
- Hold the power button (as you do) to forcefully shutdown the system

Comment: Hi Andreas,thanks for replying.  I am aware of the (very quiet) recall from Apple regarding the GPUs on the Mac Pros, but this only referred to the bigger brothers and never the entry level D300.  (You were right in your assumption)  However, it doesn't take any significant hardware decoding or 3D graphics to reproduce the issue, in fact I can be simply surfing the web or running heavy duty audio processing, it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: You said it was a hardware problem, does this mean that they need to replace the GPU as they have done with the higher spec'd models?

Comment: @Merrlyn Since the problem is so hard to reproduce, few people have been able to get the GPU replaced by Apple for free. For most of those with replacements, the crashes start again a few weeks after. As far as I know, there simply isn't a fix. :(

Comment: @ Andreas Ley  That doesn't sound great, and the crashes are definitely getting worse.  You said that some people - although rare - had managed to get the GPUs replaced but the crashes had started up again a few weeks later.   Apple did acknowledge the issue with the D500 and D700 and announced a recall.  Do you know if the problem was solved in these cases?

Comment: @Merrlyn I believe the replaced D500 and D700 work properly – or at least I have no evidence to the contrary. :)

Comment: There's some hope then at least.  In fairness to Apple, one visit to the Apple Genius Bar and they've agreed to replace both GPU and logic boards without charge.  So I'm currently awaiting the parts to arrive and then we'll see what happens next.  TBC . . .

Comment: @ Andreas Ley  You were right!

Comment: @ Andreas Ley  Apple agreed (without any fuss) to change both the logic board and the dual D300s at quite a hefty cost to themselves and without charge to me.  However, within an hour of getting the Mac Pro back the crashes started again and seem to be worse.

Comment: @Merrlyn Very sorry to hear that. :( I suggest you let Apple know and ask for maybe a D500 or so...

Comment: @ Andreas Ley Yeah, that was my thinking, although they're next move is not to look at it again until I've done a full clean, OS X reinstall (which I'm putting off the hassle of at the moment due to workload)  So sooner or later I'm just going to have to bite the bullet and then see if they'll play the upgrade to D500 game

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by MacOS crashes? As in the machine shuts off automatically for no apparent reason? The OS freezes or becomes almost unusable and you need to unplug it? If MacOS shuts off on its own while you're doing something, it may be a PSU problem and probably cannot be fixed with software unless you wanted to dualboot Windows, undervolt or underclock your processor with XTU or something, and return back to MacOS and see if the issue if gone. If it's the second one, then your fans may not be functioning properly and the CPU is just doing a fallback procedure and limiting its clock speed to somewhere under half a GHz. Both options should be able to be resolved at an Apple Store near you, unless you have been using the Mac Pro for 5 years.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.    It freezes with a permanent beachball, no attempt of time leaving it brings the system back to usable and the only resolve I've found is to crash the whole system holding the power button and then a reboot.  It ran absolutely fine on Mavericks and the problems began when updating to Yosemite, which I'd hoped would be resolved with further updates and I'm now on High Sierra, with possibly the worst and regular crashes so far.  (Mac Pro is 4 years old btw)

Comment: It does seem to be exhibiting all the issues related to the very quietly recalled versions here, but of course Apple are not prepared to go down that line at present so thought I'd post the crash/panic log and see if anyone had any thoughts.    Article here: https://www.macrumors.com/2016/02/06/late-2013-mac-pro-video-issues-repair-program/